# Форматирование текста и удаление элементов на php

Tags: php, строки

В переменной `$txt` у меня имеется текст такого формата:

```
"[id190477709|Елена], только это Ман а не КамАЗ"
"[id120080895|Лёша], но водителю КАМАЗа -слабым быть совсем не надо -ведь такая ерундень не нужна нам каждый день.)"
```

и т.п

Как мне удалить все кроме имени, что бы вместо

```
"[id120080895|Лёша], привет!"
```

получилось

```
"Леша, привет!"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть два варианта

```
$txt = "[id120080895|Лёша], привет!";

     $arr = array('[',']','|','id',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0);
echo str_ireplace($arr, '', $txt);                       // Лёша, привет!

echo preg_replace('![0-9]+|\[|\]|\||id!', '', $txt);     // Лёша, привет!
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно рассмотреть такой вариант:

```
$string = '[id120080895|Лёша], привет!';
echo preg_replace('/\[id.*?\|(.*?)\]/', "$1", $string);
```