# Как вырезать текст на php?

Tags: php

Из такого текста **"[id120080895|Лёша], привет!"** я делаю такой **"Леша, привет!"** следующим кодом:

```
$txt = $result['text'];
$arrgumentstxt = array('[',']','|','id',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0);
$formattxt = str_ireplace($arrgumentstxt, '', $txt); 
echo $formattxt;
```

Однако если исходный текст в таком формате **"[id120080895|Лёша], привет! Вот его номер +79789879878"**, то на выходе **обрезается номер**, и любые другие цифры.

Как обрезать именно [id120080895|Лёша], оставить имя, но ничего другого не трогать, например если в тексте будут находится цифры.

Comment: @KostaB. дубликат-то дубликат, однако этот вопрос задан т.к. принятое там решение не работает в определенных случаях. Автору правда следует обратить внимание на второй ответ к тому вопросу.

Answer (score 0):

Второй ответ вам подойдет:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/851287/302920

```
$string = '[id120080895|Лёша], привет! Вот его номер +79789879878';
echo preg_replace('/\[id.*?\|(.*?)\]/', "$1", $string);
```